# Open bootstrap popup from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In angular Template I have two anchors,first display text inside popoup and second one display images inside popup,Like this:

```
<a ng-click="openPopup('Text')">Text popup</a><a ng-click="openPopup('Image')">Image popup</a>
```

I have a two different popup's for Text and Images.I want to open text popup if user click "Text popup". Same like Image.
Here is the sample text and Image popup code.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="myTextModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:800px" role="document">
                //Content goes here
             </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myImageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:800px" role="document">
                //Content goes here
             </div>
    </div>
```

In controller:

```
    $scope.openPopup = function(Value) {
            if(Value=='Text'){
                //open Text popup
            }else{
                //open Image popup
            }
       }
```

I am  using ui.bootstrap.modal How can I achieve this?

Comment: It says how right in the docs https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: Did you say you are using [ui.bootstrap.modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) ? Then @Jenson's answer has the correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

save both the modals to two html file and use this to open pop up

```
$scope.openPopup = function(Value) {
        if(Value=='Text'){
            $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/text.html',
                scope: $scope
            });
        }else{
                $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/image.html',
                scope: $scope
            });
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can open modals like this

```
$scope.openPopup = function(Value) {
        if(Value=='Text'){
            $("myTextModal").modal("show");
        }else{
            $("myImageModal").modal("show");
        }
   }
```

[Bootstrap JS Modal](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)

Comment: I want it in Angular not in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a ng-hide or ng-show property to your modal html code

```
<div ng-show="showModal">
```

then all you have to do is swithcing the `$scope.showModal` to `true` whenever you want to show your modal screen and `false` to hide it.

another method is using angular-ui dependency and use $modal property which is based on bootstrap.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys for replying.
I just found my answer.
This is how we can achieve.

```
$scope.openPopup = function(Value) {
        var elementText = angular.element('#myTextModal');
        var elementImage = angular.element('#myImageModal');
            if(Value=='Text'){
                elementText.modal('show');
            }else{
                elementImage.modal('show');
            }
       }
```

Comment: Any reason for downvote? 
This is what I am looking for.